# iisnode won't run Express

Tags: node.js, iis, express, iis-8, iisnode

I'm trying to run express using iisnode. I followed the examples provided but when trying to use the latest Express version with a basic example, there's no way to make it work.

I'm getting the error `Cannot GET /node/parislight/hello.js` and other times, just a `The webpage cannot be found`.

My created a `hello.js` file (main express file) taken from [the express docs](http://expressjs.com/es/starter/hello-world.html).

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

})
```

I added the necessary `web.config` file (extracted from the express example within iisnode)

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- indicates that the hello.js file is a node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="hello.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <!-- use URL rewriting to redirect the entire branch of the URL namespace
    to hello.js node.js application; for example, the following URLs will 
    all be handled by hello.js:

        http://localhost/node/express/myapp/foo
        http://localhost/node/express/myapp/bar

    -->

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="myapp/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="hello.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I gave all the necessary permissions to the used App Pool in IIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to use the full path:

> The path specified in app.get calls must be the full path of the request.

[Source](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-express-nodejs-applications-in.html)

Looking like this now:

```
app.get('/node/parislight/myapp/demo', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

Acceding to it through:

> http://localhost/node/parislight/myapp/demo

Answer (score 3):

You can use a catch all function at the end of your file as well to get any url and send a 200 response or send your special 404 page. Note: placement has to be after all other specified urls.

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```